# Where is the Telegram API sdk or library files?

Tags: telegram

I wanna learn telegram API.

Everything start with this method => https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode

But where is the API library?
What is this API language?

I have app_id, bash and test/product IP:POST from my . telegram.

But i don't understand how can i use that method.
Curl or library or another thing maybe.

Anyone explain me please correctly and simply.

For example:

```
.... library / sdk
.... trigger address
.... PHP or another language example
```

I am reading another questions about same issue from here.
But they are not clear for me.

PS: This is my first question on this platform and my English is not good, i hope i can explain my issue

Comment: Which language do you use? Please look into https://telegram.org/apps#source-code

Comment: Here is TDLib (Telegram Database library): https://github.com/tdlib/td

Comment: I know that links, but all of them for the create  "client" like "clone telegram app".

I want to trigger to API and get authentication code.

I can create local web telegram clone and i can join and use but i cant use API or another thing.